q-binomial identity
Given the definition of q-binomial:
Let $q$ be a prime power and let $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$. We define the q-binomial coefficient  of $s$ and $t$ as:
${\binom{s}{t}_q \stackrel{\Delta}{=} \begin{cases}
                0 & \text{if} \ s<t \ \text{or} \ s,t<0  \\
                1 & \text{if} \ t=0, s\geq0 \\
                \prod\limits_{i=1}^{t} \frac{q^{s-i+1}-1}{q^i-1} & \text{otherwise}
            \end{cases} }$
How can i prove (if it is possible) in a simple way that:
\begin{equation}
        \binom{a}{b}_q \binom{b}{c}_q = \binom{a}{c}_q \binom{a-c}{a-b}_q
    \end{equation}

I think you mean $\prod$, no $\sum$. Note the $t=0$ case is subsumed into the "otherwise" case as the empty product. And all cases are just formulas corresponding to the combinatorial interpretation in Andrew's answer.

Yes, I wrote wrong, I wanted to write \prod

Suppose $q=v$ is a prime power. Then the evaluation ${\binom nr}_v$ counts the number of $r$-dimensional subspaces of an $n$-dimension vector space over the field $\mathbb F_v$ with $v$ elements.
To see this, we note that we can determine an $r$-dimensional vector space by picking a basis. The number of possibilities is therefore
$$ (v^n-1)(v^n-v)\cdots(v^n-v^{r-1}). $$
The number of bases determining the same $r$-dimensional subspaces is, by the same reasoning
$$ (v^r-1)(v^r-v)\cdots(v^r-v^{r-1}), $$
which is of course the size of the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}_r(\mathbb F_v)$. Taking the quotient we get ${\binom nr}_v$.
So now the product ${\binom ab}_v{\binom bc}_v$ counts the ways of choosing a $c$-dimensional subspace inside a $b$-dimensional subspace inside an $a$-dimensional subspace, say $U\subseteq V\subseteq W$.
We can count this differently by taking a $c$-dimensional subspace $U\subseteq W$, and then an $(a-b)$-dimensional subspace of the quotient $W/U$. The number of such is then ${\binom ac}_v\binom{a-c}{a-b}_v$.
This says that the two sides agree when evaluated at any prime power $q=v$. As both sides are polynomials in $q$, and there are infinitely many such prime powers, we see that the identity must hold as polynomials in $q$.

Out of curiosity, why the letter $v$?

I wanted to make clear the distinction between $q$-binomials as polynomials in the variable $q$, and a particular evaluation at a prime power, which is what's used in the first part of the argument. I guess I chose $v$ because of quantum groups. There one uses quantum binomials in a variable $v$, and evaluates them at prime powers $q$. Here I swapped the roles.
